# Reverse string function causes crash when accommodating 'space-bar'

Tags: c++, string, reverse

Testing Environment: Visual Studio 2010

I am trying to include 'space-bar' as part of a users input for reversing their string. There are two issues that I've come across so far.

1. if I only type in one word/character, the program crashes.
2. if I type in multiple characters with spaces, the first character/word gets skipped, the rest print, program does not crash.

---

Here is the code (I've left out parts of the code because they work just fine with or without the piece of code that's giving me issues):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void RevStrng(string &inpu, int &entry) 
{
    if (entry == inpu.size()-1) //return the length of the string, minus 1 byte
        return;
    int stored = inpu.size() - 1 - entry; //store the rearranged string in variable stored
    string firstLetr = inpu.substr(1,stored); //starting character for rearrangement
    string restOfLetr = inpu.substr(stored+1,inpu.size()); //remaining characters for rearrangement
    inpu = firstLetr + inpu.substr(0,1) + restOfLetr; //store rearrangement in pointer inpu
    RevStrng(inpu,++entry); //print rearranged string until 0 bytes left

};
int main()
{

...
...
...

    //Taking user input, and printing it backwards
    cout << "///Display string Backwards///" << endl;
    string sentnce; 
    int syze = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter characters to be read backwards: ";
    cin>>(sentnce);
    getline(cin, sentnce);
    RevStrng(sentnce, syze);
    cout << "Your entry backwards is: "<< sentnce << "\n" << endl;

...
...
...
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know they do the same thing but i even tried changing .length() to .size() and still same situation. When I try to adjust the numerical portions of my function, I get a StackOverFlowException. I have a feeling that `string firstLetr = inpu.substr(1,stored);` is causing the issue...but I don't know what to do, or where to look.

So I welcome all suggestions, if at all possible PLEASE try to hint out to me where to look at in the function, otherwise if you feel the hint would be a dead give away then up to you (but even if it is I do still want to try and figure it out).

Thank you!

Comment: Reversing a string, even if you don't use the built in `std::reverse`, is much simpler than what you've coded.

Comment: To reverse a string, it takes a simple loop with two indices, one starting at the beginning of the string (the left index) and the other starting at the end of the string (right index).  You simply swap the characters at the two indices.  Increase the left index, decrease the right index, rinse and repeat until the left index and right index meet or if the left index goes past the right index.  All of these calls to `substr` that you're doing confuses the heck out of me.

Comment: using std::reverse does seem a lot simpler lol...I guess I have over complicated things unnecessarily. I'm going to try what you said! thanks!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I took you excellent advice, did a bit of reading and after some tears, came up with this `string RevStrng(string inpu)
{ 
    reverse(inpu.rbegin(), inpu.rend());
    int startt = 0;
    int endd = 0;

    while(endd < inpu.length())
    {
        if(inpu[endd] == ' ')
        {
             reverse(inpu.rbegin() + startt, inpu.rbegin() + endd);
             startt = endd + 1;
        }
        endd--;
    }
 return inpu;
}` and it looks like it's working great so far! Just wanted to know, would this be considered a better more cleaner way of doing what i was attempting?

Comment: Spoke too soon. The bright side, it doesn't crash anymore. The downside, it still skips the first word/character and goes directly for the next one after the space. Can't understand why

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and what the desired output would be?  It seems like you want to output the words in the string in reverse order rather than reverse the whole string.

Comment: well I am to create "a member function to reverse in place the order of a given character array". so basically professor says to reverse any order of characters that has been inputted. `Example: Enter your string: abc jtf`   `Your entry: ftj cba` ....and thanks to molbdnilo it's come to my attention that I don't use a function with `std::reverse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive reversal can be written slightly simpler.

```
std::string reverse(std::string s)
{
   return s.empty() ? s : reverse(s.substr(1)) + s[0];
}
```

or in place

```
void reverse(std::string& s, int a, int o)
{
   if (a < o)
   {
      std::swap(s[a], s[o]);
      reverse(s, a + 1, o - 1);
   }
}
```

---

Edit:

If you use `std::reverse` you don't need your own function.

A complete example:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "///Display string Backwards///" << endl;
    string sentence; 
    cout << "Please enter characters to be read backwards: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);
    reverse(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());
    cout << "Your entry backwards is: "<< sentence << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: so I looked into std::reverse some more, and I've come across several examples.
I've created a while loop and it seems to work without crashing now. The only issue remaining is, I can't get it to reprint the first word or character if I have any other code before it, and also using cin >>. example:

I'll enter "hello world" as the string, and it'll print "dlrow" and completely ignore hello.

However, when I don't have any int main () coding before my reverse code and remove cin >> and only use getline, it seems to work perfectly.
here's a link to what im tryna say.
http://ideone.com/5kdgAp

Comment: everything that's commented out, allows my code to work exactly as I want for the reverse part....but as soon as you remove the commenting, it stops accepting that first string of characters before hitting space bar (hello).

Comment: `cin >> sentnce` reads until the first spaces, then `getline(cin, sentnce)` reads the rest of the line, replacing the old value of `sentnce`. And you don't need any loop at all, `reverse(inpu.rbegin(), inpu.rend());` reverses the string completely.  (Complete example in edit.)

Comment: ohhh okay, that is good to know! unfortunately my assignment requires i create a member function to reverse a string. I'll find another way.

Comment: so I'm completely stumped. I can't seem to figure it out. I tried your edited example just to see if I can get it to print back with a whitespace, example: "sixty seven" "neves ytxis", but it completely skips the user's input for entering characters to be read backwards, it just displays the questions, then exits the program (no errors). It seems like I have to use `cin >> sentence` in order to get a user's input.

Comment: i found this `cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` and it seems to make it work now! Looks like I wasn't clearing the newline buffer before the getline(cin, sentence). Thanks so much. its finally working!

Answer (score 1):

The `substr` method takes a position and count so `string firstLetr = inpu.substr(1,stored);` takes a variable length string from position 1, but it looks like you want a single letter string, so your arguments are swapped. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr for more details.

And the reason this causes a stack overflow is that you are effectively growing the `inpu` string on every recursive invocation.

But reversing a string doesn't require using `substr` at all. Storing single letter strings as a `string` is both strange and excessive. Likewise, the multiple string concatenations mean that you aren't really doing the reversal in place and you are making multiple temporary copies.

Comment: thank you for this, it's helped me understand what I was doing a lot more. I'm getting closer to a solution through everyone's suggestion and answers. thanks!